# FancyBox2 - Title on top AND on the bottom?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Found several similar questions, but not the answer to this specific one..

Is there a way to add a title to BOTH the top and bottom of a FancyBox2 modal/popup?

I know how to position the title to the top or bottom.  But need to put a title on the top and a caption on the bottom.

Thanks to all in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the default fancybox template to add some extra HTML in. Like so:

Your HTML:

```
<a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk/news' class="fancybox" data-caption="caption here" title="Title here">Click</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var caption = this.element.attr('data-caption');
        this.tpl.wrap = '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div><p>'+caption+'</p></div></div></div>'

    },

    helpers:  {
        title : {
            type : 'inside',
            position: 'top'
        }
    }
});
```

I've used an iFrame as an example, but this should work for any Fancybox type.

JS Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WillDonohoe/thy0om73/

Look under the tpl section of the fancybox docs for more information: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Excellent suggestion Will.  And I was just reading about the template.  Yet your example makes it much clearer than the general docs.  Nice work.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 : you could also do `var caption = $(this.element).data('caption');`